# How to sort Objects in an Array in Ascending Order in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have previously asked this question somewhat but it was not clear enough.

I need to sort Employee Objects by their Age by creating a method in Department Class.
I have searched and searched but I cannot seem to figure this out as I am getting rather frustrated so any help would be great. 
Also the Company Class is where my main method is. The main concern here is Comparing the Ages of Employee Objects and then Sorting them if an Employee is in   Departments Information Systems or Accounting ONLY.

I know about Comparable and Comparator but have no idea how to implement them properly even after research.

Thanks.

**CODE**

Employee Class:

```
public class Employee implements Comparable {

private String name;
private int age;
private String department;

public String getDept(){
    return department;
}//end dept

public void setDept(String dept){
    this.department = dept;
}//end

public String getName(){
    return name;
}//end name

public void setName(String n){
    this.name = n;
}//end

public int getAge(){
    return age;
}//end age

public void setAge(int a){
    this.age = a;
}//end




public Employee (String n,int age,String dept){

    this.name = n;
    this.age = age;
    this.department = dept;

}//end employee
}//end class
```

Department Class:

```
public class Department   {




}//end department
```

Company Class:

```
public class Company {


public static void main(String [] args){

    Employee[] e = new Employee[13];
    PrimeAgeChecker p = new PrimeAgeChecker();
    Department d = new Department();

    e[0] = new Employee("Counting Guru",55,"Accounting");
    e[1] = new Employee("Counting Pro",45,"Accounting");
    e[2] = new Employee("Counting Savvy",40,"Accounting");
    e[3] = new Employee("Counting Novice",25,"Accounting");
    e[4] = new Employee("Sales Guru",50,"Marketing");
    e[5] = new Employee("Sales Pro",48,"Marketing");
    e[6] = new Employee("Sales Savvy",38,"Marketing");
    e[7] = new Employee("Hiring Guru",58,"Human Resrouces");
    e[8] = new Employee("Hiring Pro",47,"Human Resrouces");
    e[9] = new Employee("Hacking Pro",47,"Information Systems");
    e[10] = new Employee("Hacking Guru",51,"Information Systems");
    e[11] = new Employee("Hacking Savvy",38,"Information Systems");
    e[12] = new Employee("Hacking Novice",23,"Information Systems");


    for(int i = 0;i<e.length;i++){
        System.out.println(e[i] + " " + p.isPrime(e[i]));
    }//end 





}//end main
}//end company
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparable and Comparator provide 2 different sorting mechanisms. Comparable is useful for Objetcs with a natural ordering, such as words or numbers. For an Employee Object, this might be an employee id.

Comparator provides a mechanism for sorting Objetcs based on some arbitrary method and allows for Objects to be sorted in many different ways as required.

Both `java.util.Collections` and `java.util.Arrays` provide method for working with Comparable Objects, and sorting using Comparators.

Your problem is based on sorting Integers, which have natural ordering. Please check the documentation for `java.lang.Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get familiar with [Arrays.Sort(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) where you can pass an comparator:

[Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
MyComparator implements Comparator<Employee>.... and implement your logic
```

second you need to sort your Array:

```
Arrays.sort(e,new MyComparator());
```